# Performance increase, code optimization of JQuery + json array code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

By looking into many resources, I've figured out how to write following code, which process json array (data) and with 250ms delay shows result and adds class 'petstatusok' (or 'petstatusno') to existing element with class 'pet-items':

```
if (data.cat & data.cat !== 'null') {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pet-items:nth-child(2)').addClass('petstatusok');
    $('#label-cat').val((data.cat).trim());
  }, 250);
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pet-items:nth-child(2)').addClass('petstatusno');
  }, 250)
}

if (data.dog & data.dog !== 'null') {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pet-items:nth-child(3)').addClass('petstatusok');
    $('#label-dog').val((data.dog).trim());
  }, 500);
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pet-items:nth-child(3)').addClass('petstatusno');
  }, 500)
}
```

and so on... I have 24 blocks like this...

I do believe that there is a place to optimize the code... 
My thoughts:

- Is there any possibility to have a loop to reduce the number of code lines/increase performance?
- Is there any possibility with *setTimeout(function ()* to place it somewhere in code only once?
- Any other opportunities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `forEach` and calculate the child number and delay based on the index.

As @Ray said is his answer, `null` is not a string (unless your JSON is wrong) so you should remove the quotes and use `&&` in this case. You actually don't even need to check for the `null` because it is falsy so `if (data[pet])` will suffice.

I have assumed that `cat` is the first 'pet' child in `.pet-items`.

```
const pets = [
    'cat',
    'dog',
]
pets.forEach((pet, index) => {
    const child = index += 2
    const delay = (index + 1) * 250
    if (data[pet]) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(`.pet-items:nth-child(${child})`).addClass('petstatusok');
            $(`#label-${pet}`).val(data[pet].trim());
        }, delay);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(`.pet-items:nth-child(${child})`).addClass('petstatusno');
        }, delay)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, in the end I selected your solution - works well.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function that can be called multiple times, with all the repeatable variables being used as input parameters - petType (name of the pet, which is a string) and index, which starts from 1.

```
function setStatusAndLabel(petType, index){
    if (data[petType] && data[petType] !== null){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.pet-items:nth-child('+index+')').addClass('petstatusok');
          $('#label-'+petType).val((data[petType]).trim());
        }, 250);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.pet-items:nth-child('+index+')').addClass('petstatusno');
      }, 500)
    }
}
```

Next,

If `data` is an object with exclusively 24 items and nothing else, you could do a for loop through `data` like this:

```js
var counter = 1;
for (var petType in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(petType)) {
        setStatusAndLabel(petType.toString(), counter++);
        if (counter === 24){
        // so that it doesn't continue to loop through the object's prototype methods, if any, after your work is done.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

OR

If `data` has other stuff in addition to the 24 items, then you need to specify what the required items are. You can do this with an array, then loop through it.

```js
var requiredItems = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow',... (so on)];
requiredItems.forEach(function(petType, index){
    setStatusAndLabel(petType, index);
});
```

(End)

---

By the way,

- you should check for `null` like this `data[dataType] !== null` and not like this `data[dataType] !== 'null'`
- `&` is the bitwise operator and `&&` is the logical operator. You should use `&&`.